# Invalid column name 'CalanderDate'. when using a with and a union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, union

i have the following query :

```
WITH Calender AS 
(
    SELECT @FromDate AS CalanderDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalanderDate + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE CalanderDate + 1 <= @ToDate
)
INSERT INTO #C
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25)
     , case [dbo].[CalculateNumericWeekCode] (4, CalanderDate)
         when 1 then 'A'
         when 2 then 'B'
         when 3 then 'C'
         when 4 then 'D'
         end
        , TT.Name
    , 'Green'
    , 'Green'
    , FREQ.pageid
    ,''
FROM Calender,
     TransportType AS TT INNER JOIN #F AS FREQ ON FREQ.TransportTypeID = TT.TransportTypeId
     WHERE TT.TransportTypeID = @TransportTypeID
UNION
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25)
     , case [dbo].[CalculateNumericWeekCode] (4, CalanderDate)
         when 1 then 'A'
         when 2 then 'B'
         when 3 then 'C'
         when 4 then 'D'
         end
     , TT.Name
    , Case INC.incidentstatusid
       when 6 -- Approved
          then 'Blue'
       else
          ''
      END
    , 'Green'
    , FREQ.pageid
    ,''
FROM Calender,
     TransportType AS TT INNER JOIN #F AS FREQ ON FREQ.TransportTypeID = TT.TransportTypeId
     INNER JOIN [Incident] AS INC on FREQ.Task = INC.Task AND FREQ.Contract = INC.Contract AND CalanderDate = INC.[EstimatedCompletionStamp]
     INNER JOIN [IncidentStatus] AS INCSTAT ON INCSTAT.IncidentStatusID = INC.IncidentStatusID
     INNER JOIN [IncidentSubType] AS INCSTYP ON INCSTYP.incidentsubtypeid = INC.IncidentSubTypeID and INC.IncidentSubTypeID in (20,21,22,23) and INC.TransportTypeId = TT.TransportTypeID
```

My #C-table is declared as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #C
(  
  DateOfTransport DateTime not null,
  WeekCode varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  [TransportType] varchar(25) NULL,
  [CSDColor] varchar(10) not null,
  [WWWColor] varchar(10) not null,
  [PageID] int not null,
  [ToolTip] varchar(250) null
)
```

Now when I run the query, I get the message : Invalid column name 'CalanderDate'.

when I remove the UNION it works fine.
But I do need the union between the different tables.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why are you mixing implicit joins with explicit ones? Always explicit joins. they are a part of ansi-sql for over 20 years now.

Comment: Also, try to remove the first query so that you will know if the problem is the union itself or just the second query that is causing the problem. Using union with a CTE is working fine in my sql server 2012.

Comment: I already removed the first query and the problem is in the second query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the problem:

As I suspected, it's caused by your mixture of join styles:

This `on` clause is invalid `on FREQ.Task = INC.Task AND FREQ.Contract = INC.Contract AND CalanderDate = INC.[EstimatedCompletionStamp]` since you are using an implicit join on `calander`.

I think that this should work:

```
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CalanderDate,25)
     , case [dbo].[CalculateNumericWeekCode] (4, CalanderDate)
         when 1 then 'A'
         when 2 then 'B'
         when 3 then 'C'
         when 4 then 'D'
         end
     , TT.Name
    , Case INC.incidentstatusid
       when 6 -- Approved
          then 'Blue'
       else
          ''
      END
    , 'Green'
    , FREQ.pageid
    ,''
FROM TransportType AS TT 
     INNER JOIN #F AS FREQ ON FREQ.TransportTypeID = TT.TransportTypeId     
     INNER JOIN [Incident] AS INC on FREQ.Task = INC.Task AND FREQ.Contract = INC.Contract 
     INNER JOIN Calender ON CalanderDate = INC.[EstimatedCompletionStamp]
     INNER JOIN [IncidentStatus] AS INCSTAT ON INCSTAT.IncidentStatusID = INC.IncidentStatusID
     INNER JOIN [IncidentSubType] AS INCSTYP ON INCSTYP.incidentsubtypeid = INC.IncidentSubTypeID and INC.IncidentSubTypeID in (20,21,22,23) and INC.TransportTypeId = TT.TransportTypeID
```

Comment: Or, if they wanted to maintain the original table ordering (for whatever reason), they could use `CROSS JOIN`.